# What shape is formed by averaging a circle and square using a mid-point approach

Tags: geometry

Imagine a circle of radius 5 units. Thus, it has a diameter of 10 units. Form a square whose side length is also 10 units. The square and the circle have the same center point. (Assume the origin.) Note that the circle intersects the square exactly four times. Now, imagine drawing every radius from the center of the circle to the circle's edge. Extend each of these radiuses such that they intersect the square. Each ray intersects the circle once and the square once. Find the mid-point between these two intersections.

What would that shape look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's part of the family of curves known as a "superellipse".  See

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html

The name is from Piet Hein. Perhaps you also describe a "squircle", See

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squircle.html

I'll leave it to you to figure out what exactly you have!